# How to wire up a PSC motor from a air conditioning unit?

Tags: motor, induction-motor

[[image: Wiring 1]

I hope someone can help with this. I have a LG air conditioning compressor motor. (PSC type motor). It has three terminals not labelled. Its new but came without a wiring diagram. I've searched the net and found various pieces of information but not sure exactly how to connect it up.

I have attached some screen shots of the motor spec and a sketch of how I think it needs to be connected.
The resistance readings across the terminals do not match the spec exactly, they are slightly higher at 4.5 ohms.

Any help would be great.

[image: Motor type]

[image: Resistance Values]

[![Wiring Diagram][3][4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YVW7A.png)

[image: wiring diagram 2]

Comment: Could you attach the datasheet pdf or send us a link to it?

Comment: Please see link:

Comment: https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=http://www.amifrigo.com/media/wysiwyg/GK113PAH.pdf&ved=2ahUKEwi704L64qHvAhVVu3EKHS4kAgUQFjABegQIAhAC&usg=AOvVaw1AZ4NQnSqEyrMeYC54NwqM

Answer (score 2):

You probably have the common terminal identified correctly, but you could be right or wrong with S & R. It may be that the S & R windings are identical and you connect the capacitor to either to select direction of rotation.

The motor may be a "universal replacement" that is designed to replace motors on a variety of products. If you know which way it is supposed to turn, take a guess at S & R and connect it to power without installing it. Hook it up through a switch and switch on very briefly. If it turns the right direction, your guess is right. Then turn it on and check the current. If you know the rated current, you can compare with that. No-load current could be 30 to 50 percent of rated current, so that doesn't tell you very much, but if the current is more than 60 percent of rated, I would be worried.

Install the motor if it seems ok, double check that the direction of rotation is right and check the current both immediately after start and after the compressor has warmed up.

Comment: Thanks for answer.

Comment: The compressor is designed to run one way in a refrigerant system. Although the data sheet gives different resistance readings for the two windings I get the same reading on both.

Comment: See revised answer.

Comment: .Ok thank you for the info. I've got the live going to the common terminal and Neutral to the R terminal. Would this be right?

Comment: Yes. The motor probably has an internal overload protector between the common point between the windings and the external common connection. If you connect that to live, it disconnects live from the windings when it opens. That is what you want.

Comment: Thank you for your help

Comment: Tested works great. Drawing 1.7amps with not load. Rated amps is 4 so think its ok. Thanks for your help